# Java URI escaper which works like the Javascript's unescape

Tags: javascript, java, escaping, urldecode, unescapestring

I have a string like `http://google.com/search/q=<%= name %>`.

A third party js library that I have no control over is escaping this to `"http://google.com/search/q=%3C%=%20name%20%%3E"`

which Javascript can successfully unescape to the original string with

```js
unescape("http://google.com/search/q=%3C%=%20name%20%%3E")
```

But Java's `URLDecode.decode("http://google.com/search/q=%3C%=%20name%20%%3E")` throws an `IllegalArgumentException` because of the unescaped literal `%` character in the string which is of course correct and according to spec, but this makes server-side processing complicated.

Before I try to fix the bad JS escape on the server-side with regular expressions (because, as mentioned, I cannot modify the JS side), I would like to know if there is a more permissive Java URL/URI decoding API which would work in the same way as Javascript's `unescape`, i.e. which would ignore standalone '%' characters and only decode whatever is decodable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick look around some Apache libraries and came up against the same issue.  Interestingly enough when I followed up in the EMCAScript Language Spec, I found pseudo code for the unescape() function.  You can see this at https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-unescape-string

It's easy enough to put together a simplistic implementation of this (see below) and at least for the example in your question the output matches.

Now this code is in no way optimized and I haven't though about whether character encoding is relevant, but it may be a less painful way forward than trying to wrestle things out with Regex.

```
public static String unescape(String s) {
    StringBuilder r = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length();) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == '%') {
            if (looksLikeUnicode(s, i)) {
                r.append((char) fromHex(s, i + 2, i + 5));
                i += 6;
                continue;
            }
            if (looksLikeAscii(s, i)) {
                r.append((char) fromHex(s, i + 1, i + 2));
                i += 3;
                continue;
            }
        }
        r.append(s.charAt(i));
        i += 1;
    }
    return r.toString();
}

private static boolean looksLikeUnicode(String s, int i) {
    return (i + 5 < s.length()) && (s.charAt(i + 1) == 'u') && areHexDigits(s, i + 2, i + 5);
}

private static boolean looksLikeAscii(String s, int i) {
    return (i + 2 < s.length()) && areHexDigits(s, i + 1, i + 2);
}

private static boolean areHexDigits(String s, int from, int to) {
    for (int i = from; i <= to; ++i) {
        if (isNotHexDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static boolean isHexDigit(char c) {
    return (c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f');
}

private static boolean isNotHexDigit(char c) {
    return !isHexDigit(c);
}

private static int fromHex(String s, int from, int to) {
    return Integer.parseInt(s.substring(from, to + 1), 16);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much! Once you mentioned ECMAScript I realized that in fact java's native ScriptingEngine can be used to do the JS-style escaping, i.e. `new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn").eval("unescape(\"%3C%=%20name%20%%3E\")")`, but that brings the unnecessary overhead of instantiating the scripting engine, so I am marking this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Nice.  I should have thought of the scripting engine.  It is a more robust solution, but yes, a little heavier.